# How to set height of <tr> of both tables which are adjecent and in separate divs?

Tags: html

I have 2 tables in two adjecent divs.height of tr(table row) of first table does not match that of second table. I want height of tr(table row) of both tables should be same.So how can i set/adjust height of second(right) tables's tr(table row) according to height of left table's tr(table row) ? plz help.. it should work in different resolutions..

Comment: Either set a fixed height or use JavaScript to make sure they are both equal height.

Comment: also this should work in different resolutions..plz anybody can provide js code?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$tableheight2 = $('#table2').height();
$tableheight = $('#table1').height();


if($tableheight >= $tableheight2)
{

$('#table2').height(($tableheight);

}else{

$('#table1').height($tableheight2);

}
```

Making it with tr:

```
$trheight = 0;

/* loop all tr in function */
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {

  /* replace $strheight with tr height when smaller */ 
  if($(this).height()>$strheight){
    $strheight=$(this).height();
  }
}

/* loop all tr and replace the height with $strheight */
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {
   $(this).height($strheight);
}
```

Comment: Hello Joeri, i want to set tr's height,not tables height..do u have any solution ?

Comment: This isn't correct: `$('#table2').height() = $tableheight;`, this is: `$('#table2').height($tableheight);`. Also, it needs to run on the cells of each row I believe.

Comment: edited my answer with code for TR / thx @powerbuoy for correcting my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Or with css, to a fixed height:

```
<style>
    table tr {
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I'd set the height to the `td` instead. But perhaps setting it to the `tr` works.

Comment: That is just one idea, user that asked the question can experiment with it.